# Securing WCF (asmx) Call From Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, wcf

Currently, the code calls the WCF method from Azure Function and everything works properly.

The task now is the WCF has no security. I need to secure the WCF AND then get the client (Azure Function) to implement the same security.

Language is C# in both client and host.

Problem is; Azure Functions does not have a config file to add in the  endpoints and security. My attempts to add it through code;

```
PortalServicesSoapClient psSoapClient = new PortalServicesSoapClient(new 
PortalServicesSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration(), url);
                
psSoapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MyUsername";
psSoapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MyPassword";
```

To the host .asmx

```
public class AuthHeader : SoapHeader
{
    public string UserName;
    public string Password;
}
```

Result in the AuthHeader being null.

Testing with Postman does pass in the UserName and Password successfully, but not from Azure Function.

Partial script from postman

```
<soap12:Header>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <UserName>MyUsername</UserName>
        <Password>MyPassword</Password>
    </AuthHeader>
</soap12:Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, Azure functions are public.You deploy them and the endpoint is available publicly via the address on the function.

So You can set function level access. It means you need to pass an access key.
Also there are some other ways to secure Azure Functions.You can refer to the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, but I have secured the function; through access key. Trying to secure the call to WCF from the Azure function. The WCF security is the issue.

Comment: If this solution has other problems, you can read the docs and try another way.